# What is Most Efficient Way to Split Python List

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a vector that is always a multiple of the objects `M` and `K`. In the example below, `M=2` and `K=3` the vector is of length 6. What I want to find is the best way to use use the values of `M` and `K` to split my list so it results in a pandas dataframe with `M` columns and `K` rows in each column.

I can see a way to loop over the list and grab and organize the stuff I need. However, I'm assuming there is a more efficient way and hoping someone can help point that out.

```
import pandas as pd
result = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
M = 2
K = 3
A = pd.DataFrame(result[0:3])
B = pd.DataFrame(result[3:6])
final = pd.concat([A.reset_index(drop = True), B], axis = 1)
```

Comment: No, the answer below is correct with M columns and K rows

Comment: yep, didn't see the `axis=1`

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something like:

```
import numpy as np
...
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(result).reshape(K, M))
```

And actually, you want:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(result).reshape(K, M, order='F'))
```

Comment: @dhc actually, look at the edit, you want to reshape in fortran order

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Ah, you edited faster than I commented. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One efficient solution that gets the same values in `final` would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
final = pd.DataFrame(np.array(result).reshape(M,K).T)
```

This `reshape`s a flat `numpy` array to the intended dimensions, then reads it in transposed order (`.T`) to get the values descending first along the columns first, then across rows)